# To Do List in JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, sorting

I have set up this To Do List and almost everything is working perfect. However, if I delete everything in the list. It won't let me add a new entry and I can't seem to figure it out why. It will work fine as long as I have at least one entry on the list.

Any help is much appreciated thank you.

```js
< head >
  < script type = "text/javascript" >
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  function addTask() {
    if (document.forms[0].newtask.value == "")
      window.alert("You must enter a value in the New Task field.");
    else {
      if (document.forms[0].tasks.options[0].value == "tasks")
        document.forms[0].tasks.options[0] = null;
      var newTask = new Option();
      newTask.value = document.forms[0].newtask.value;
      newTask.text = document.forms[0].newtask.value;
      var numTasks = document.forms[0].tasks.options.length;
      document.forms[0].tasks.options[numTasks] = newTask;
      document.forms[0].newtask.value = "";
    }
  }

function deleteTask() {
  var selectedTask = 0;
  var taskSelected = false;
  while (selectedTask < document.forms[0].tasks.length) {
    if (document.forms[0].tasks.options[selectedTask].selected == true) {
      taskSelected = true;
      break;
    }
    ++selectedTask;
  }
  if (taskSelected == true)
    document.forms[0].tasks.options[selectedTask] = null;
  else
    window.alert("You must select a task in the list.");
}

function ascendingSort() {
  var newTasks = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].tasks.length; ++i) {
    newTasks[i] = document.forms[0].tasks.options[i].value;
  }
  newTasks.sort();
  for (var j = 0; j < document.forms[0].tasks.length; ++j) {
    document.forms[0].tasks.options[j].value = newTasks[j];
    document.forms[0].tasks.options[j].text = newTasks[j];
  }
}

/*]]>*/
< /script>

    <title>To Do List</title >
< /head>
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>To Do List</h1>
  <form action="">
    <p>New Task
      <input type="text" size="68" name="newtask" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="Add Task" onclick="addTask()" style="width: 150px" />
      <input type="button" value="Delete Selected Task" onclick="deleteTask()" style="width: 150px" />
      <br />
      <input type="button" value="Ascending Sort" onclick="ascendingSort()" style="width: 150px" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <select name="tasks" size="10" style="width: 500px">
        <option value="tasks">Tasks</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete all your tasks you are having an empty `select`, with no `options`.

You need to guard your condition in your `addTask` function with

```
document.forms[0].tasks.options.length > 0
```

Something like this:

```
if (document.forms[0].tasks.options.length > 0 && document.forms[0].tasks.options[0].value == "tasks")
    document.forms[0].tasks.options[0] = null;
```

See [code updated](http://jsfiddle.net/y9etf49v/)

Answer (score 1):

When all task get deleted, then

```
            document.forms[0].tasks.options[0].value //throw an error as 

            document.forms[0].tasks.options[0] //is undefiend
```

So I have used as

```
             if (typeof document.forms[0].tasks.options[0] != 'undefined' && document.forms[0].tasks.options[0].value == "tasks")
                    document.forms[0].tasks.options[0] = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code crashes here as you can see with the jsconsole of your browser

```html
 if (document.forms[0].tasks.options[0].value == "tasks")
```

You try to read options[0].value after setting options[0] to null in

```html
document.forms[0].tasks.options[selectedTask] = null;
```

Try not to destroy your data structure when deleting an item